# Gps wrong location

Tags: android, gps, location

I made an android application. I run application on laptop and located me at one place(in a wrong town about 250 km). When run application on my desktop with another api key, located me on the same wrong city. Can anyone tell me where is the problem? Thank you!

Comment: Are you moving at relativistic speeds when running your tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, Android won't acquire a location just because your Wi-Fi will inherit that to the Emulator.

You need to follow some steps:

1. Be sure to have the following permissions in your Android Manifest:

   android.permission.INTERNET

   android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE

   android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION

   android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

   android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS

   android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION

   android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE

   android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE
2. Be sure to have the maps library in your Application tag:

   ```
   <application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
           <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
   </application>
   ```
3. Be sure to have a valid Maps API Key in your MapView in your /layout/map.xml file.
4. Because you are not running your App on an actual device, the only way to send different locations to your App is to push a MOCK LOCATION. To do so, simply Launch your App in the Emulator, go to the DDMS perspective in Eclipse IDE, and look for the options on the left (reset the DDMS perspective if you can't find them). It should look like this:

[image]

Select the Emulator Name under the "Devices" Tab, then you can send Latitude and Longitude coordinates using the "Location Controls".

When you are done developing and testing, be sure to remove the ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION permission and to test the location detection on an actual phone or tablet with either GPS, aGPS chip or Cellular/Wifi Network.

Comment: You are welcome! I just fixed the answer to be clearer and because the Rich Text Editor messed the XML in the permissions. Good luck!

Comment: Mmm... sometimes you need to convert the latitude and longitude returned by the location API by multiplying or dividing by 1E6.

E.g:
Double latitude = location.getLatitude()*1E6;
Double longitude = location.getLongitude()*1E6;

locationPoint = new GeoPoint(latitude.intValue(),longitude.intValue());

Comment: locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        
  double lat = location.getLatitude()*1E6;
  double lng = location.getLongitude()*1E6;
        
  GeoPoint locationpoint = new GeoPoint((int) lat, (int) lng);
  MapController mc = mapView.getController();
  mc.animateTo(locationpoint);
  mc.setZoom(15);

Comment: I receive an error when I run on emulator. (The application MapsApp(process net.learn2develop.GoogleMaps) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again. Force close). Do you think that I obtain in a correct way the location?

Answer (score 1):

When you run a mobile application on desktop simulator, which doesn't have GPS in it, you will get some fixed location every time. To get real GPS coordinates  you need to install it in a android device and test it.

** Update **

If you are having the same problem on your phone too, then your phone GPS is probably switched off, which you need to turn on, or phone is using Wifi to get a fix on its location.

Comment: I import the application on android device and shows me the same wrong position

Comment: I turn on the GPS and the results are the same :(

Comment: I receive an error when I run on emulator. (The application MapsApp(process net.learn2develop.GoogleMaps) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again. Force close).

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, is the phone getting the GPS location through your home wifi network rather than the phone's GPS? Might explain why they both give the same wrong value.

Comment: Yes indeed, my phones getting GPS location through my wifi network. So, tell me how can I do to repair this problem?

Comment: If I turn off the wifi of the phone and I start the application, it shows me only a grid, not the map. Only when I connect the phone through wifi and restart the application appear the map.

Comment: You should be able to turn on the built in GPS on your phone using the settings! So long as your phone has it, which I thought all android phones had